# How to measure the distance between multiple points and multiple polygons?

Tags: qgis, vector, distance

I'm trying to find a quick and accuarate way to measure the distance between 3 survey sites and all the designated sites within 10km. The survey sites are on a point vector layer and the designated sites are polygons, both on the same CRS.

I am new to GIS and so far I have only been able to measure the distance to the nearest designated site. As I said I need to know the distance to the nearest boundary of all the sites within 10km, not just the nearest.

Comment: distance as the crow flys or drive time? ET geowizards has a tool that will perform it. however it is not free. Calculates the distance for each feature of the Input dataset to the closest feature from the Near dataset. In the attribute table of the output the distance is recorded together with the ID of the closest feature.

Inputs: 

Input Dataset - Point, Multipoint, Polyline or Polygon 
Near Dataset  - Point, Multipoint, Polyline or Polygon 
Search tolerance - the maximum distance to search for features in the near layer in the units of the spatial reference of the Input Dataset

Comment: I think it would be worth your while to have a look at the MMQGIS plugin. It is optional so you have to go to `PLUGINS|MANAGE INSTALL PLUGINS` then search for MMQGIS and install. Use the `MMQGIS|CREATE|HUB DISTANCE` command. But I am not certain of your use case, so have to try yourself.  Help is at http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Comment: Are you open to trying a Spatial Database solution like Spatialite or PostgreSQL w/ PostGIS?

Answer (score 1):

This  may  be  a  bit  more  work  than  you  want  to  do, but  if  you  edit  the  layers with  advanced  digitizing  enabled, you  can create  a  new  feature  starting  at  a  point and  as  you  move  the  mouse  around  to  other  points  and  positions the  distance  is  displayed  in  the advanced  digitizing  panel. You  can  then  copy  down  the  distance. You may  be  able  to  use  a  variant  of  this  by  drawing  feature  that  connect  various  points and  getting  the  dimensions  for  each significant  edge.

This is  definitely  a  work  around or  kludge, but  you  might  want  to  try  it